# Web api controller selection by route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have two different class library that contains same name controllers.

```
namespace OldApiService{
   public class GreetingController: ApiController{
       public string Get(){ return "hello from old api"; }
   }
}

namespace NewApiService{
   public class GreetingController: ApiController{
       public string Get(){ return "hello from new api"; }
   }
}
```

And I have a main We Api applciation that contains Route and other helper classes. This application references `NewApiService` and `OldApiService` assemblies.

```
namespace MyApi {
    public class Startup 
    {            
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder) 
        { 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration(); 
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
                name: "DefaultApi", 
                routeTemplate: "api/{api}/{controller}/{id}", 
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
            ); 

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I want to select a controller that specified url parameter.

`http://localhost:4035/api/old/greeting`  will use **OldApiService** Controller

`http://localhost:4035/api/new/greeting`  will use **NewApiService** Controller

I tried to change url route settings but not worked. Duplicated controller error occurred.

Is there any way to override the controller selection mechanism. Simply I will get route value (old or new) and select the controller from specified namespace.

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'greeting'.
>   This can happen if the route that services this request
>   ('api/{version}/{controller}/{id}') found multiple controllers defined
>   with the same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported.
>   The request for 'greeting' has found the following matching
>   controllers: OldApiService.GreetingController
>   NewApiService.GreetingController

I think this is an important issue for asp.net web api.

Comment: If you have control of both libraries consider using attribute routing as there will always be a conflict via convention-based routing as it looks at the control name when mapping routes.

Comment: Have you tried using the RoutePrefix attribute?

Comment: Yes I tried Route attribute but did not worked

Comment: @bookmarker Show how you tried rout attribute. Include webapi config as well

Answer (score 2):

Old library

```
namespace OldApiService{

    public static class WebApiConfig {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
            config.config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();        
        }
    }

   [RoutePrefix("api/old/greeting")]
   public class GreetingController: ApiController{
       [Route("")]
       public string Get(){ return "hello from old api"; }
   }
}
```

Other library

```
namespace NewApiService{

    public static class WebApiConfig {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
            config.config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();        
        }
    }

   [RoutePrefix("api/new/greeting")]
   public class GreetingController: ApiController{
       [Route("")]
       public string Get(){ return "hello from new api"; }
   }
}
```

Start up

```
namespace MyApi {

    public class Startup { 
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder) {

            var config = new HttpConfiguration(); 

            //Map attribute routes

            OldApiService.WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            NewApiService.WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            //convention-based routes
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
                name: "DefaultApi", 
                routeTemplate: "api/{api}/{controller}/{id}", 
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
            ); 

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config); 
        } 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the RoutePrefix/Route attributes.

```
namespace OldApiService{
   [RoutePrefix("api/old/greeting")]
   public class GreetingController: ApiController{
       [Route("")]
       public string Get(){ return "hello from old api"; }
   }
}

namespace NewApiService{
   [RoutePrefix("api/new/greeting")]
   public class GreetingController: ApiController{
       [Route("")]
       public string Get(){ return "hello from new api"; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Remember to also show how to expose the configuration for the two libraries

Comment: Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'greeting'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('api/{version}/{controller}/{id}') found multiple controllers defined with the same name but differing namespaces, which is not supported. The request for 'greeting' has found the following matching controllers: OldApiService.GreetingController NewApiService.GreetingController